# How to clean up old artifacts of Liferay Service Builder?

Tags: liferay, code-generation, code-cleanup, liferay-service-builder

Based on `service.xml`, Liferay's [Service Builder](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/running-service-builder-and-understanding-the-generated-code) generates Java files, directories, other files and database tables. It also extracts interfaces from code written after this generation.

When I rename a method or delete a class, Liferay does not clean up anything, the methods/classes/tables just stay there.

How to clean these old artifacts from a portlet project, with the same effect as if I re-wrote it from scratch again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: First make backups.

## Clean the filesystem

- Exit any IDE like Liferay IDE, Liferay Studio, Eclipse.
- run `ant clean` to clear out generated artifacts so you can ensure the only thing left is your code after following the rest of the steps below.

Temporarily move your implementation files from `docroot/WEB-INF/src/yournamespace/service/impl` out of the way, for instance move it to your home folder.

Delete the following folders (and all of their sub-folders) from your portlet project:

- `docroot/WEB-INF/service`
- `docroot/WEB-INF/sql`
- `docroot/WEB-INF/src/yournamespace` (make sure again that you have moved your implementation files to a safe place)

## Clean the database

1. Open your `service.xml`
2. Take note of the content of the `<namespace>` tag, for instance `MyNamespace`
3. In your Liferay database, drop all tables that start with that namespace plus an underscore, for instance `MyNamespace_`.

## Re-generate

- Run the Service Builder
- Move your implementation files back to `docroot/WEB-INF/src/yournamespace/service/impl`
- Run the Service Builder again

*Feel free to add your tips and more things to clean!*